# Identify the Conic Section

Tags: code-golf, math

Given 5 distinct points on a two-dimensional plane, determine the type of conic section formed by the points. The output shall be one of `circle`, `hyperbola`, `ellipse`, or `parabola`.

#### Rules

- The points will be in general linear position, meaning that no three points are collinear, and thus the conic passing through them will be unique.
- The coordinates of the 5 points will be decimal numbers between -10 and 10, inclusive.
- The precision for the decimal/float values should be the precision of your language's native float/decimal type. If your language/data type is arbitrary-precision, you may use 12 digits after the decimal point as the maximum required precision, rounding toward zero (e.g. `1.0000000000005 == 1.000000000000`).
- Capitalization of the output does not matter.
- Outputting `ellipse` when the conic section is actually a circle is not allowed. All circles are ellipses, but you must output the most specific one.

On floating point inaccuracies and precision:

> I'm trying to make this as simple as possible, so that issues with floating point inaccuracies don't get in the way. The goal is, if the data type was "magical infinite precision value" instead of float/double, then everything would work perfectly. But, since "magical infinite precision value" doesn't exist, you write code that assumes that your values are infinite precision, and any issues that crop up as a result of floating point inaccuracies are features, not bugs.

#### Test Cases

```
(0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 3), (4, 8), (9, 2) => hyperbola
(1.2, 5.3), (4.1, 5.6), (9.1, 2.5), (0, 1), (4.2, 0) => ellipse
(5, 0), (4, 3), (3, 4), (0, 5), (0, -5) => circle
(1, 0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 9) => parabola
```

Comment: For floats, outputs like `circle` seem to require checking float equality to distinguish from a very round ellipse. What precision should we assume here?

Comment: @xnor Native precision of your language/data type

Comment: @Mego Why not allow the integer version of the problem for all languages , but with a wider range, e.g. -10000 to 10000.

Comment: I agree with @orlp. My solution is failing on your circle problem because of precision while you could have just made an integer test case.

Comment: would it be fine if I used `numpy.isclose` because of inaccuracies?

Comment: are you sure test case four is correct? desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fmwrjau8fd

Comment: Also, 3 looks wrong too: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tkx1wrkotd

Comment: A link to the wikipedia page on [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section)

Comment: @orlp Ah, I was messing up my calculations. I'll add a test case for the circle soon.

Comment: No need to worry about FP precision guys. Every ellipse is a circle so you can just output `ellipse` !

Comment: @feersum I should hope that it's obvious that doing that is not allowed.

Comment: @Maltysen The test cases have been corrected. `numpy.isclose` would not be acceptable (nor needed), because Python's floats are not arbitrary-precision, and thus you would use `a == b` for equality. If `a` and `b` are within 1 ULP of each other, they will compare equal, and thus should be treated as equal.

Comment: What do you mean `within 1 ULP` ?

Comment: @edc65 I mean within 1 [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). It's very simple: if `a == b`, then the difference between the values that `a` and `b` are trying to represent is less than 1 ULP.

Comment: I think you are understimating the problems with FP accuracy, and that leads to answer like this http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77815/21348

Comment: @Mego Yeah, you are making some really unrealistic assumptions about floating point computations. It is true that each individual floating-point operation is accurate to within 1 ULP. However, when you compose several floating-point operations, the sub-ULP errors get magnified at each step, so that the final result may be much less accurate. For example, (1/49)*49 != 1.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I'm trying to make this as simple as possible, so that issues with floating point inaccuracies don't get in the way. The goal is, if the data type was "magical infinite precision value" instead of float/double, then everything would work perfectly. But, since "magical infinite precision value" doesn't exist, you write code that assumes that your values are infinite precision, and any issues that crop up as a result of floating point inaccuracies are features, not bugs.

Comment: @Mego In that case, I don’t understand your objection to Maltysen’s answer. It seems to interpret the question the same way.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg It's less objecting and more confusion. See [my comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77746/identify-the-conic-section?noredirect=1#comment189946_77815).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Matlab, 154 bytes

```
p=input();c=null([p.^2 prod(p,2) p 1+p(:,1)*0]),s={'circle' 'ellipse' 'parabola' 'hyperbola'};s{3+sign(c(3)^2-4*c(1)*c(2))-~max(abs(c(3)),abs(c(1)-c(2)))}
```

Saved some bytes thanks to Suever's suggestions.

Takes input as `[x1 y1;x2 y2;x3 y3; etc]`. This used a Vandermonde matrix, and finds the basis of its null space, which will always be a single vector. Then it calculates the discriminant and uses it to make an index between 1 and 4 which is used to get the string.

Ungolfed:

```
p=input();
c=null([p.^2 prod(p')' p ones(length(p),1)]);
s={'circle' 'ellipse' 'parabola' 'hyperbola'};
s{3+sign(c(3)^2-4*c(1)*c(2))-~max(abs(c(3)),abs(c(1)-c(2)))}
```

The `sign(...)` part calculates the discriminant, giving 1 if it's positive (hyperbola), -1 if it's negative (ellipse), and 0 if it's 0 (parabola). The `max(...)` subtracts 1 away if it is a circle. Matlab arrays are one-indexed, so add 3 to give values 1, 2, 3, 4, and use that to index the array of conic section names.

Comment: Rather than comparing `max() == 0` you can simplify to `~max()`

Comment: Also instead of `ones(length(p),1)` you could do `1+p(:,1)*0`

Comment: Cheers, the `max()` thing was silly of me, I did have comparisons there before and got lazy obviously! That way of getting the `ones` is very nice too.

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES6), 316 <s>323 347</s>

```js
p=>[1,2,4].some(x=>(d=D(Q=[[x&1,x&2,x&4,0,0,0],...p.map(([x,y])=>[x*x,x*y,y*y,x,y,1])]))?[a,b,c]=Q.map((v,i)=>D(Q.map((r,j)=>(r=[...r],r[i]=x*!j,r)))/d):0,D=m=>m[1]?m[0].reduce((r,v,i)=>r+(i&1?-v:v)*D(m.slice(1).map(r=>r.filter((a,j)=>j-i))),0):m)&&(d=b*b-4*a*c)?d<0?!b&c==a?'Circle':'Ellipse':'Hyperbola':'Parabola'
```

Any language better suited for handling matrix and determinant should score better (APL, J, CJAM, Jelly)

References: [General form of a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section), [Five points determine a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic), [System of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations), [Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)

In the cartesian plane, the general equation of a conic is

```js
A*x*x + B*x*y + C*y*y + D*x + E*y + F = 0
```

having A or B or C not equal to 0 (otherwise it's a straight line)

A ... F are six unknowns to be found. With five pairs of (x,y) we can build a linear system with five equations, and scaling remove one dimension. That is, we can set one of A,B or C to 1 if it's not 0 (and we know that at least one is not 0).

I build and try to solve 3 systems: first trying A=1. If not solvable then B=1, then C. (There could be a better way, but that's my best at the time)

Having the values of A,B,C we can classify the conic looking at the discriminant `d=B*B-4*A*C`

- d == 0 -> parabola
- d > 0 -> hyperbola
- d < 0 -> ellipse, particularly (A == C and B == 0) -> circle

**Less golfed**

```js
F=p=>(
  // Recursive function to find determinant of a square matrix
  D=m=>m[1]
    ?m[0].reduce((r,v,i)=>r+(i&1?-v:v)*D(m.slice(1).map(r=>r.filter((a,j)=>j-i))),0)
    :m,
  // Try 3 linear systems, coefficients in Q
  // Five equation made from the paramaters in p
  // And a first equation with coefficient like k,0,0,0,0,0,1 (example for A)  
  [1,2,4].some(
    x => (
      // matrix to calc the determinant, last coefficient is missing at this stage
      Q = [ 
        [x&1, x&2, x&4, 0,0,0] // first one is different
        // all other equations built from the params 
        ,...p.map( ([x,y]) => [x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, 1] )
      ],
      d = D(Q), // here d is the determinant
      d && ( // if solvable  then d != 0
        // add missing last coefficient to Q
        // must be != 0 for the first row, must be 0 for the other
        Q.map( r=> (r.push(x), x=0) ),
        // solve the system (Cramer's rule), I get all values for A...F but I just care of a,b,c
        [a,b,c] = Q.map((v,i)=>D(Q.map(r=>(r=[...r],r[i]=r.pop(),r))) / d),
        d = b*b - 4*a*c, // now reuse d for discriminant
        d = d<0 ? !b&c==a ? 'Circle' : 'Ellipse' // now reuse d for end result
        : d ? 'Hyperbola' : 'Parabola'
      ) // exit .some if not 0
    ), d // .some exit with true, the result is in d
  )  
)
```

**Test**

```js
F=p=>[1,2,4].some(x=>(d=D(Q=[[x&1,x&2,x&4,0,0,0],...p.map(([x,y])=>[x*x,x*y,y*y,x,y,1])]))?[a,b,c]=Q.map((v,i)=>D(Q.map((r,j)=>(r=[...r],r[i]=x*!j,r)))/d):0,D=m=>m[1]?m[0].reduce((r,v,i)=>r+(i&1?-v:v)*D(m.slice(1).map(r=>r.filter((a,j)=>j-i))),0):m)&&(d=b*b-4*a*c)?d<0?!b&c==a?'Circle':'Ellipse':'Hyperbola':'Parabola'

console.log=(...x)=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;[
 [[0, 0], [1, 5], [2, 3], [4, 8], [9, 2]]
,[[1.2, 5.3],[4.1, 5.6], [9.1, 2.5], [0, 1], [4.2, 0]]
,[[5, 0], [4, 3], [3, 4], [0, 5], [0, -5]]
,[[1, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [3, 4], [4, 9]]
].forEach(t=>console.log(t.join`|`+' => '+F(t)))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: This is really nice! Excellent work!

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 234 bytes

```
import numpy as n
x=input()
d=[n.linalg.det(n.delete(n.array([[i*i,i*j,j*j,i,j,1]for i,j in x]),k,1))for k in range(6)]
t=d[1]**2-4*d[0]*d[2]
print"hyperbola"if t>0else"parabola"if t==0else"circle"if d[1]==0and d[0]==d[2]else"ellipse"
```

I never print `circle` or `parabola` because `t` and `d[1]` never hit exactly `0`, but OP said that was okay.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 500

My JavaScript answer ported to C. Just to see if it can be done.

Usage: read 10 values from standard input

> echo 1 0 0 1 2 1 3 4 4 9 | conic

Output:

> Parabola

[Test (ideone)](http://ideone.com/ECm7fm)

```c
double D(m,k)double*m;{double t=0;for(int s=1,b=1,x=0;x<6;x++,b+=b)k&b||(t+=s*m[x]*(k+b>62?1:D(m+6,k+b)),s=-s);return t;}i,u,h;double m[36],*t=m+6,w[6],s[3],b,d;main(){for(;i++<5;*t++=d*d,*t++=d*b,*t++=b*b,*t++=d,*t++=b,*t++=1)scanf("%lf%lf",&d,&b);for(u=4;u;u/=2)for(m[0]=u&1,m[1]=u&2,m[2]=u&4,d=D(m,0),h=0;d&&h<3;h++){for(i=0;i<6;i++)w[i]=m[i*6+h],m[i*6+h]=i?0:u;s[h]=D(m,0)/d;for(;i--;)m[i*6+h]=w[i];}b=s[1];d=b*b-4*s[0]*s[2];puts(d?d<0?!b&(s[2]==s[0])?"Circle":"Ellipse":"Hyperbola":"Parabola");}
```

**Less golfed**

```c
// Calc determinant of a matrix of side d
// In the golfed code, d is fix to 6
double D(m, d, k)
double*m;
{
    int s = 1, b = 1, x = 0;
    double t = 0;
    for (; x < d; x++, b += b)
        k&b || (
            t += s*m[x] *(k+b+1==1<<d? 1: D(  m + d, d, k + b)), s = -s
        );
    return t;
}

double m[36],d, *t = m + 6, w[6], s[3], a, b, c;
i,u,h;
main()
{
    for (; i++ < 5; )
    {
        scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &b);
        *t++ = a*a, *t++ = a*b, *t++ = b*b, *t++ = a, *t++ = b, *t++ = 1;
    }
    for (u = 4; u; u /= 2)
    {
        m[0] = u & 1, m[1] = u & 2, m[2] = u & 4;
        d = D(m, 6, 0);
        if (d) 
            for (h = 0; h < 3; h++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    w[i] = m[i * 6 + h],
                    m[i * 6 + h] = i ? 0 : u;
                s[h] = D(m, 6, 0)/d;
                for (; i--; )
                    m[i * 6 + h] = w[i];
            }
    }
    a = s[0], b = s[1], c = s[2];
    d = b*b - 4 * a * c;
    puts(d ? d < 0 ? !b&(c == a) ? "Circle" : "Ellipse" : "Hyperbola" : "Parabola");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 247 bytes

```py
def f(p):
 for i in[1,2,4]:
  z=[i&1,i&2,i&4,0,0,0]
  M=matrix([z]+[[x*x,x*y,y*y,x,y,1]for x,y in p])
  try:A,B,C=(M\vector(z))[:3]
  except:continue
  d=B*B-4*A*C
  return['parabola','hyperbola','circle','ellipse'][[d==0,d>0,d<0and B==0and A==C,d<0].index(1)]
```

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFUs1ugzAMvlfqO_jUBOYioHRa0VKp9NwnyDgwSLVIjKKQVtCnX5zSDmTZsf19_kkadYYz74N8uYDzxYAG3ckEU8xKcsFdSL1KUK9SJxnG9JcUOInfyho9cnkv36QcwxHHcMLJyYgTJiWxOcvxQV8GBLFmyg9Y4FHw09dN1fZi-D0IZL7xjGqsVW_z-tJZ3V0VuRpRhMU6Cw_hkY5G2avpJOsrU31f2ooh-5l6ZWa71qZulTNU2-p-UKyUshEixmbv5DOuugYKdyZ9EOJIvjLSXaNGngSuh-XCqsEOIIAxxmOEOEDgCcKWdIqwIZ0hfJDeIaQBiD28elgueBK5tG30SIwIGr37ZLLTyBM54uQRT6kEUcwdO4LtXDWbq20Qshn0BK-3HvMYl2rOkCdvOusn1FHtPOK1N8ZoWLqhuhoUXZEfPBr6VttWd2rg_kW4jwLoNk9boeRHDmfEx4L_HKFuVcvJmp290Z11b8u7PMMfioGfWw==&lang=sage)

This function takes an iterable of `(x,y)` pairs as input, tries computing the discriminant of each of the 3 possible linear systems (`A=1`, `B=1`, and `C=1`), and outputs the type of conic section based on the values of the discriminant, `A`, `B`, and `C`.

There's probably some more golfing to be done, but I'm rusty with Sage and sleepy right now, so I'll work on it more in the morning.